# Rails Fixtures - Is possible to haver identifiers endind with numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, fixtures

I've faced the following situation: Having many like registers in my fixture, I've tried numbering them:

```
# nutrients.yml
nutrient_1:
  name: Protein

nutrient_2:
  name: Fat

# daily_intakes.yml
daily_intake_1:
  nutrient: nutrient_1
  sex: m
  amount: 200g

daily_intake_2:
  nutrient: nutrient_1
  sex: f
  amount: 100g
```

When I tried to run rake test:units, I've got the following errors:

```
>  1) Error: ArticleTest#test_relationships:
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column
> 'nutrient' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `daily_intakes` (`nutrient`,
> `amount`, `sex`, `id`) VALUES ('nutrient_1', '200', 'm', 787678763)
```

I can't figure why Rails doesn't references nutrient_1 instead of using it as a string.

So, i've tried:

```
# nutrients.yml
a:
  name: Protein

b:
  name: Fat

# daily_intakes.yml
daily_intake_1:
  nutrient: a
  sex: m
  amount: 200g

daily_intake_2:
  nutrient: a
  sex: f
  amount: 100g
```

And it works! But I'd like to keep the numbers... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, and interesting as I've not seen this issue. Why not just name them like so:

```
nutrient_one
nutrient_two
```

or without an underscore

```
nutrient1
nutrient2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't get what happened. I've tried a smaller data set (but keeping the "model_number" convention) and now it works.

Using words is not feasible because it was auto generated (it would take too long)